# Spring Rest repository builder like Spring roo and MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, roo

Spring roo is a project to build MVC applications in minutes with JPA support (I think... I've never used it).

Well, exist any spring project like roo to build Spring Rest Repositories with CRUD methods for an existing database?

Answer (score 1):

Well, trying spring boot I found that a spring boot app with all the jpa repositories defined and a connection configured to the database, spring boot provide all the CRUD Rest methods by default.

JHipster could help too... that tool build the entire project from a database model